# Combinatorics - Arrange 5 Men & 12 Women Around The Table

Tags: combinatorics

I have this problem - in how many ways I can arrange **5 men** & **12 women** around the table **if no two men can sit together?**

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about a possible solution? Or can you tell what you have tried and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we must have some kind of blocks.

Men-$M_1, M_2,...,M_5.$

Women-$W_1,...,W_{12}.$

First block - $M_1W_1$, second- $M_2W_2$,..., fifth- $M_5W_5$.

In between of every block we can seat up any number of women, and only $7$ are left alone.

Now you have to seat up $5+7$ people. Then multiply it by $2$ (blocks can be either MW or WM) and, then again multiply it by $12\choose 5$, because it's the number of women we used in blocks, and we can select any $5$ of them.

Comment: so solution is 12! / 5! * 7! ?

Comment: @MLN96  That is incorrrect.  As you found, there are $11!$ ways to arrange the women in a circle.  We now have $12$ gaps in which to place the men, one to the right of each woman.  We can place the first man in $12$ ways, the second in $11$ ways, and so forth.  Thus, there are $11! \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 = \frac{11!12!}{7!}$ possible arrangements.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Why we have 12 gaps? I think that when we arrange 12 women then we have 5 gaps.

Comment: @MLN96  We have $12$ gaps because we can place a man to the right of any of the women.  Since there are only five men, we fill just five of those $12$ gaps, which can be done in $12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:  Have the women stand around the table.  Then have each man, one after another, find two women to stand between.  Then have everyone sit.